Code running fine in jupyter notebook but Visual studio is running the cell continuously and not giving output
import random

chance = 0

random_integer = random.randint(0, 10)

while chance <= 2:
    n = int(input("Guess the number between 1 to 10:"))
    
    if (n < 0 or n > 10):
        print("number out of range")
        chance+=1
        
    else:
         # Generate a random integer between 0 and 10 (inclusive)
        if (n == random_integer):
            print("You Win")
            break
            
        elif (n > random_integer):
            print("number guessed is greater than the lucky number")
            chance +=1
            
        elif (n < random_integer):
            print("number guessed is less than the lucky number")
            chance+=1

print("Lucky number was:",random_integer)

I tried installing the latest python version and changing the python interpreter path to new one, but it's still not working.

I was unable to reproduce the issue

Do you get an error message of some kind? Do you see the input prompt? Tell us more about what exactly you see, because as asked, your problem is not reproducible.

But its working fine in Jupyter
error -
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

check this code
import random

chance = 0

random_integer = random.randint(0, 10)

n = int(input("Guess the number between 1 to 10:"))

while chance <= 2: 

    if (n < 0 or n > 10):
            print("number out of range")
            chance+=1
            
    else:
             # Generate a random integer between 0 and 10 (inclusive)
            if (n == random_integer):
                print("You Win")
                break
                
            elif (n > random_integer):
                print("number guessed is greater than the lucky number")
                chance +=1
                
            elif (n < random_integer):
                print("number guessed is less than the lucky number")
                chance+=1
print("Lucky number was:",random_integer)


It would be better if you stated what change you have made and why you think it is necessary

This doesn't let the user enter a new guess at each iteration of the loop, how is this supposed to answer the question?

But its working fine in Jupyter
error -
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
